# How do I get my discord bot to forward its dms

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I saw the similar question when writing this but that was 2 years ago and when I tried it it didn't work. This is the code I was able to come up with

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild:
        return
    channel = client.get_channel(793586177328283660)
    await channel.send(message)
```

and whenever he gets dmed he says something in the channel but not what I wanted. He says this: `<Message id=811285760304218153 channel=<DMChannel id=811037483255988274 recipient=<User id=760967899388051486 name='Ledip4001' discriminator='2308' bot=False>> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=760967899388051486 name='Ledip4001' discriminator='2308' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>`.
Probably something else when someone else dms him but I want him to say the right thing. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

`message` is a `Message` object with a bunch of information about the message, not just the message itself. `message.content` is what contains the message itself. Use `await channel.send(message.content)` to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Its said that message has no attribute .txt

Comment: Figured it out I put.content

Comment: @LedipLedip oops typed wrong thing... fixed it just now

Comment: @Ledip make sure to accept answers that work for you